# R: ts() with NA data

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, imputets

I have following function:

```
ts.dat <- ts(data=dat$sales, start = 1, frequency = 12)
```

ts. dat returns

```
   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
1 9000 8600 8500 8600 8500 8300 8600 9100 8800 8700 9300 7900
2 7900 8800 8500 8900 9000 8800 8800 9100 9500 8900 9200 8400
3 8400 9200 9500 9100 8700 8300   NA
```

However,

```
 plot(stl(ts.dat, s.window=12))
```

returns

```
Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object'plot':
```

I tried `na.action=na.pass`, but it didn't work. Any idea how to deal with the NA, if that is the reason?

Also: Any chance to take the first date from `dat` as the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea how to deal with the NA, if that is the reason?

You need to use `na.action = na.omit`, i.e., dropping `NA` when doing computation.

```
plot(stl(ts.dat, s.window=12, na.action = na.omit))
```

[image: stl]

The `na.pass` will simply assume `NA` as normal observation. But it will still produce error as `stl()` later calls compiled code and can not recognize `NA`.

> Any chance to take the first date from `dat` as the start?

Have a look at the examples at the bottom of `?ts`:

```
 ## Using July 1954 as start date:
 gnp <- ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(100), 2)),
           start = c(1954, 7), frequency = 12)
```

To start from July 1954, put `start = c(1954, 7)`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I only wondered if it's somehow possible to automate this so that not with every new dataset that already has a date, this column needs to be adjusted. I thought it could be possible to read that information from the first "month" row from dat.

Comment: I think this solution has a problem: if you simply take out the NA values, your data does not have the same "dates". For example, if you have  Day 1: 3, Day 2: NA, Day 3: 5, then na.omit will result in Day 1: 3, Day 2: 5. This can cause problems with seasonality and trends, in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

You could also impute the missing data in your time series.
(replacing the NA with a reasonable value)

There are R packages to do this (e.g. **imputeTS** or **zoo**).

Especially **imputeTS** has some functions that are very good choices for replacing missing data in time series with seasonality. (na_seadec() or na_kalman())
(it also has other imputation function - here an [overview](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-009/RJ-2017-009.pdf))

A solution here would look like this:

```
library(imputeTS)
x <- na_seadec(ts.dat)
plot(stl(x, s.window=12))
```